# Show Windows Form using Shortcut key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I am creating a windows Form application in .Net.My requirement is when I will press 'shift+alt+h' the form should be hide and when I will press 'shift+alt+s' the form should be visible.

I am able to hide the window but not able to show please suggest me how would I do.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that once you hide your application's window, it can no longer receive normal key events.  To listen for the key combination that should re-activate your window after your window has been deactivated, you will need to use global keyboard hooks.  I would look at the [Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks .Net Libary in C# on CodePlex](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Dan sir, does it is possible to achieve the solution without using this library if yes then please help me

Comment: You can opt to not use this library or any other library, but why would you want to spend development time doing something that has already been done?

Comment: Well, in my opinion, unless your "seniors" are trying to teach you to become a low level windows expert on global event hooks, they are unwise to make you write the code yourself.  Why are they okay with using the .Net framework, if they don't want you to use a 3rd party library?  That's all .Net is: a collection of libraries.  My suggestion to you would be to study this code on codeplex, and some of the examples on CodeProject, in order to implement this yourself.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable time and your nice suggestion I will try to figure out how I can do

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using forms `KeyDown` event

```
 private void YourForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
           else if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                this.Show();
            }
```

provided that this form is child form in MDI form.